# Cannot listen to bootbox hidden.bs.modal event

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dom-events, bootbox

I have to listen to all modal hidden events usign the bootstrap standard events:

```
$(document).on("hidden.bs.modal",".modal",function(){
   ...
});
```

I need to use this event also for bootbox dialogs, but this doesn't work. Looking into the bootbox source I found (row 659 of https://github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/blob/master/bootbox.js):

```
 dialog.one("hidden.bs.modal", function(e) {
      // ensure we don't accidentally intercept hidden events triggered
      // by children of the current dialog. We shouldn't anymore now BS
      // namespaces its events; but still worth doing
      if (e.target === this) {
        dialog.remove();
      }
});
```

If this bootbox callback is called before my callback I'm hopeless because this destroy the calling object.

Is it possibile to bypass this problem? How can I have a call for all modal hidden events (also for bootbox modals)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'onHidden' for version 5.4.

```
bootbox.alert({
        message: 'You message',
        onHidden: function(e) {
            /* e is the hide.bs.modal event */
            if($(".modal").hasClass('show')){
                $('body').addClass('modal-open');
            }
        } 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `...` code could be encapsulated, you could subscribe to the event for each Bootbox call you make. Something like:

```
function doSomethingWhenModalCloses(){
    ...
}

bootbox
    .alert('I am an alert!')
    .on('hidden.bs.modal', doSomethingWhenModalCloses); // repeat for other functions
```

This is obviously not optimal, but Bootbox doesn't really provide a built-in way to delegate those events in a global manner.

Answer (score 0):

So I know this is an old post, but it's not answered. Here is my working solution

```
 dialog.on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    console.log('SHOW ME WHEN HIDDEN!')
 })
```

To show it in context I've done a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/500578/)